# Click on an image and open a new browser tab

Tags: r, shiny

I have the following snippet of code:

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  div(
    div(
      div(
        img(src="img_1.png", filetype="image/png", height="40px", width="120px", style="float: left;")
      ),
      div(
        img(src="img_2.png", filetype="image/png", height="40px", width="80px", style="float: right;")
      ),
      style='display: inline-block; width: 100%;'
    ),
    # rest of code
  )
  # rest of code
))
```

I would like to link a link to each of the two images, so that when the user clicks on the image (for example `img_1.png`) a new browser page opens with the chosen link. For example, if I click on `img_1.png` it opens a new page on the browser and connects to the site `"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page"`. How can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `a()` tag. add `target = "_blank"` if you want to open a second tab.

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  div(
    div(
      div(
        a(href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page", img(src="img_1.png", filetype="image/png", height="40px", width="120px", style="float: left;"))
      ),
      div(
        a(href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page", img(src="img_2.png", filetype="image/png", height="40px", width="80px", style="float: right;"))
      ),
      style='display: inline-block; width: 100%;'
    ),
    # rest of code
  )
  # rest of code
))
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. I have used it in various parts of my code. In some cases, however, when I hover over the image with the mouse, an underscore forms next to the image. How do i remove it?

Comment: I was trying to reproduce it to give you a specific solution, but I can't right now. However, I know what you mean, I've seen it before. It happens when the link has a `hover: underscore` css property. When you hover, it triggers the underscore and the image properties are such that you see the underscore. You can get rid of it by modifying the image display properties, but it's specific to the conditions, so I can't give a general solution.